# How to align UILabel's baseline to the bottom of a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to align a UILabel's baseline to the a UIImageView's bottom. I found I couldn't choose the baseline of the label as the attribute of the label. However, I also found I could use baseline if a replace the image view with another label.

Is there a way to align a label's baseline to an image's bottom?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things the nib editor just won't let you do. You will need to configure that constraint in code.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** With recent versions of Xcode you can do what the poster wants.

**Previous answer:**
This is how you can do it programmatically:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *layoutConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint 
    constraintWithItem:_imageView 
             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                toItem:_textLabel 
             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline 
            multiplier:1.0f
              constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:layoutConstraint];
```