# How to align baseline of two different UILabel without using StoryBoard

Tags: ios, iphone, alignment, uilabel, vertical-alignment

I'd like to align tow UILabel which have different font size for each.

I'm trying to do it without using StoryBoard but I can't.

In the screenshot, the baseline of the two UILabel is different.

[image]

And my code is like below,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initLabel1];
    [self initLabel2];

    [self addSideConstraint];
    [self addBaseLineConstraint];
}

- (void)initLabel1
{
    _label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 120, 50)];
    _label1.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    [self.view addSubview:_label1];

    _label1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    _label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    _label1.text = @"abcjkg";
}

- (void)initLabel2
{
    _label2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _label2.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    [self.view addSubview:_label2];

    _label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:36];
    _label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _label2.text = @"abcjkg";

}

- (void)addSideConstraint
{
    NSLayoutConstraint *layoutConstraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                             constraintWithItem:self.label2
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:self.label1
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                             multiplier:1.0f
                                             constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:layoutConstraint2];
}

- (void)addBaseLineConstraint
{
    NSLayoutConstraint *layoutConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                            constraintWithItem:self.label2
                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline
                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                            toItem:self.label1
                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline
                                            multiplier:1.0f
                                            constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:layoutConstraint];
}
```

I reffered the following questions and others but I couldn't get good answer so far.

[How to align UILabel's baseline to the bottom of a UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387351/how-to-align-uilabels-baseline-to-the-bottom-of-a-uiimageview)

If you know the good way to align two UILabels, could you please tell me the way ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by myself without using constraints.

I post fixed code and screenshot.

Thank you.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initLabel1];
    [self initLabel2];
}

- (void)initLabel1
{
    _label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _label1.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    [self.view addSubview:_label1];

    _label1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    _label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    _label1.text = @"abcjkg";
}

- (void)initLabel2
{
    _label2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _label2.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    [self.view addSubview:_label2];

    _label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:36];
    _label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _label2.text = @"abcjkg";
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self layoutLabel1];
    [self layoutLabel2];
}

- (void)layoutLabel1
{
    CGSize selfSize = self.view.frame.size;
    CGSize fitSize = [_label1 sizeThatFits:selfSize];
    _label1.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, fitSize.width, fitSize.height);
}

- (void)layoutLabel2
{
    CGSize selfSize = self.view.frame.size;
    CGSize fitSize = [_label2 sizeThatFits:selfSize];

    CGFloat x = CGRectGetMaxX(_label1.frame);
    CGFloat y = CGRectGetMaxY(_label1.frame) - fitSize.height + _label1.font.descender - _label2.font.descender;
    CGFloat width = fitSize.width;
    CGFloat height = fitSize.height;

    _label2.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
}
```

[image]